# Posting to Wicket via ajax and replacing the current location

Tags: ajax, forms, wicket

I need to post form data via ajax, wait for the server reply and then replace the current page with a new one using window.location.replace(), because I don't want the current page to be kept in browser history.

Here is what I've tried so far in JS:

```
function ajaxSubmit(formId, submitAnchorId, replaceWithPageUrlAnchorId) {
    var  postData = $("#" + formId).serializeArray(),
         url = $("#" + submitAnchorId)[0].href;
    var posting = $.post(url, postData);
    posting.done(function(data) {
      window.location.replace($("#" + replaceWithPageUrlAnchorId));      
    });
}
```

The new page url must come from server code, it could be part of the reply to the data submission, or (like I imagined) it can be set in a dedicated href attaching a BookmarkablePageLink to it beforehand (which in my case is "pageaftersubmit").

In my PageWithForm.html I have:

```
  <form id="myform" method="post" style="display: none;" >
        <input type="text" id="domdiv0" name="domdiv0" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="domdiv1" name="domdiv1" value="" />
        <input type="text" id="domdiv2" name="domdiv2" value="" />
        <a href="#" id="formsubmitbutton" wicket:id="formsubmitbutton"/>
        <a href="#" id="pageaftersubmit" wicket:id="pageaftersubmit"/>
  </form>
  [...]
  <div onclick="ajaxSubmit('myform','formsubmitbutton','pageaftersubmit')" >
```

And here is the relevant server side code:

```
public class PageWithForm extends WebPage {
[...]
    BookmarkablePageLink fsub = 
       new BookmarkablePageLink("formsubmitbutton", MyPage.class);
    BookmarkablePageLink fredirect = 
       new BookmarkablePageLink("pageaftersubmit", SomeOtherPage.class); 

[...]

public class MyPage extends WebPage  {
  public MyPage(PageParameters pp) {
  }
}
```

All seems to work, except MyPage does not receive any parameters. Now I'm pretty sure there must exist easier ways to accomplish what I need, maybe even using a simple AjaxButton ([or this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Calling+Wicket+from+Javascript)), but I don't get how I can stop the browser from putting the current page into history if use those methods, while waiting for server reply before replacing the current location.

Comment: please, look for answer's update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `AjaxButton`.

On your `PageWithForm` replace both of your links by one:

```
/*[...]*/
final AjaxButton submitLink = new AjaxButton ( "formSubmitButton", myForm )
{
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit ( final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form )
    {
        /* [your post values will be stored at input fields models] */
        /*...*/            
        /* 
         * 'AjaxRequestTarget' object can execute js code, and you can
         * generate url for your wicket pages with 'urlFor' method.
         * Also, you can define page parameters according to submition info.
        */
        target.appendJavaScript ( 
            "window.location.replace('" + 
                urlFor ( SomeOtherPage.class, new PageParameters () ) + "')" );
    }
}
/*[...]*/
```

In HTML also replace your links with another `input` element:

```html
<form ... >
    <!--your inputs-->
    <input type="submit" wicket:id="formSubmitButton" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Also, you should remove `<div onclick=...` element from markup. Your form will be submited with added button.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I just realized, that you don't use wicket components for form realization (this is strange). So to get parameters you should use following in `onSubmit` method:

```
RequestCycle.get ().getRequest ().getPostParameters ().getParameterValue ( "domdiv0" );
```

But you must to specify at least wicket `Form` component in your java class to allow `AjaxButton` work properly.

In your page, just add:

```
/*[...]*/
Form myForm = new Form("myform");
/*create submitLink describe above*/
form.add ( submitLink );

add ( form );
/*[...]*/
```

In html:

```
<form wicket:id="myform" style="display: none;">
    <!-- everyting else is same -->
</form>
```

And now I see, that you also want to hide form for some reason, so `<div onclick...>` should not be removed, I guess, and now you have to define `id` parameter for `formSubmitButton` and use:

```
<div onclick="$('#formSubmitButtonId').click();">submition</div>
```

But anyway, I think you should [read more](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/forms2.html) about wicket `Form` and how to implement it.

Comment: Your solution is perfect! I wasn't using wicket components for the form fields only because in my solution I wasn't handing the form processing to wicket. However the update to your answer is very informative and can be useful for other situations, so please don't remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Of course I won't delete it :). Thank you for your reply.